# Custom django rest parser

Tags: python, django, post, django-rest-framework

This is my code:

```
class lista_libros(APIView):
def post(self, request, format=None): #, format=None
    cadena64 = request.data
    xmlfile = base64.b64decode(cadena64)
    #serializer = PruebaSerializer(data = xmlfile)
    #if serializer.is_valid():
        #serializer.save()
        #return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(xmlfile)
```

This is what I get:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>&lt;libro&gt;
&lt;nombre&gt;Juego de tronos&lt;/nombre&gt;
&lt;autor&gt;Pablo Perez.&lt;/autor&gt;
&lt;categoria&gt;Fantasia&lt;/categoria&gt;
&lt;editorial&gt;Mexicana&lt;/editorial&gt;
&lt;fecha_pub&gt;1992&lt;/fecha_pub&gt;
&lt;no_pag&gt;5000&lt;/no_pag&gt;
&lt;/libro&gt;</root>
```

Why the lower and greater than symbols appear like &lt and &gt instead < and >

this code is just for trying to POST a base64 string and decode it into a xml file.

Comment: Did you tried to add `content_type="text/xml; charset=utf-8"` to your response?

Comment: Yes, I tried that way but I'm still having the same problem, when I trie to serialize it I can't because the xmlfile variable is an String instead an XML

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root><non_field_errors><list-item>Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str.</list-item></non_field_errors></root>

Answer (score 0):

That is because the renderer that was used to render the response is HTMLRenderer. DRF determine the renderer to use [by using content negotiation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/):

> The set of valid renderers for a view is always defined as a list of
>   classes. When a view is entered REST framework will perform content
>   negotiation on the incoming request, and determine the most
>   appropriate renderer to satisfy the request.
>
> The basic process of content negotiation involves examining the
>   request's Accept header, to determine which media types it expects in
>   the response. Optionally, format suffixes on the URL may be used to
>   explicitly request a particular representation. For example the URL
>   http://example.com/api/users_count.json might be an endpoint that
>   always returns JSON data.

Use **.xml** at the end of the URL and it should pick XMLRenderer.

In order to limit the response to xml, specify XMLRenderer in you view:

```
class MyView(APIView):

    renderer_classes = (XMLRenderer,)

    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your time to answered!, I'm using a custom parser: from rest_framework.parsers import BaseParser
from rest_framework import parsers

class PlainTextParser(BaseParser):
 """
 Plain text parser.
 """
 media_type = "text/plain"
 format = 'UTF-8'
 render_style = 'text'

 def parse(self, stream, media_type=None, parser_context=None): #"text/plain; charset=utf-8"
     """
     Simply return a string representing the body of the request.
     """
     return stream.read()

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root><non_field_errors><list-item>Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str.</list-item></non_field_errors></root>