# Attempting to serialize into XML returns an error in XML

Tags: python, mysql, django, python-2.7, django-rest-framework

My code:

```
class lista_libros(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None): #, format=None
        #import pdb;pdb.set_trace()
        peticion_cadena = request.data
        xml_decode = base64.b64decode(peticion_cadena)
        #root = ET.fromstring(xml_decode)
        serializer = PruebaSerializer(data = xml_decode)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
        #   return Response(serializer.data)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root><non_field_errors><list-item>Invalid data. Expected a dictionary, but got str.</list-item></non_field_errors></root>
```

I want to serialize the content data and save it into my MySQL Database, any help is welcome! :)

Comment: POST:     PGxpYnJvPg0KPG5vbWJyZT5KdWVnbyBkZSB0cm9ub3M8L25vbWJyZT4NCjxhdXRvcj5QYWJsbyBQZXJlei48L2F1dG9yPg0KPGNhdGVnb3JpYT5GYW50YXNpYTwvY2F0ZWdvcmlhPg0KPGVkaXRvcmlhbD5NZXhpY2FuYTwvZWRpdG9yaWFsPg0KPGZlY2hhX3B1Yj4xOTkyPC9mZWNoYV9wdWI+DQo8bm9fcGFnPjUwMDA8L25vX3BhZz4NCjwvbGlicm8+

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom django rest parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509681/custom-django-rest-parser)